# what is good pattern to de serialize object?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, serialization

I have a class imagine Entity, Entity class wants to provide deserialize method this method accept a xml string and it will rebuild the object. 
which one looks better?
1- having a constructor which accept xmlString parameter and there deSerilaize Entity.
2- having a constructor without parameter and then call deserialize method with xmlString.
3- having a static method in Entity accept xmString as parameter and return a deserialized Entity as a function   call.
or any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. An object shouldn't be concerned with Serializing/Deserializing themselves at all. Those operations should be handled by an object that is dedicated to handling the serialization logic.

Not only does this make the `Entity` class simpler to work with, but it also opens your architecture to be flexible and handle different serialization methods in the future. Remember, decoupling behavior in your application is good.

Comment: you mean each object should have another object to Serialize/Deserialize it?

Comment: @Mojtaba_Sarooghi - No. Serialization is completely separate. Your `Entity` class shouldn't know anything about it. There should be no coupling between the two.

Comment: Then I have to figure out how should I serialize each object in serializer (imagine I do not want to use attribute) how my object can say to serializer about the properties it want to serialize? how about custom circular reference? 
If I got it right (I do not think so :-) ) you mean another object are aware of de/serializing the whole object graph of Entity? then again we have coupling.(serializer  should know about the details of Entity and its logic)

Comment: @Mojtaba_Sarooghi - That's exactly what I'm saying. The serializer should have some concept of what to serialize (public fields) and how to properly handle circular references, etc.

Comment: mmmm
So here we have problems about private fields, open/close principle, and also scattering of logic, also imagine serializer should have knowledge of any classes in object graph...
then I am with putting de/serializer in the object (just in case I am have meta-data opportunity I like the concept of extra serializer) but agree about coupling